# Is the /usr/lib directory prioritized over LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable while resolving the dependencies at run time on linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, elf

One of the elf file when run loads the /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 even when the LD_LIBRARY_PATH was pointing to a directory with a newer lib file and throwing  following error

```
./qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86_64-offline.run: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
```

Does the **/usr/lib** have higher precedence than **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**? Please point to the man page or other docs where this is documented.

Answer (score 0):

See `man ld.so`:

> If a library dependency does not contain a slash, then it is searched for in the following order:
>
> o (ELF only) Using the directories specified in the DT_RPATH dynamic
>   section attribute of the binary if present and DT_RUNPATH attribute
>   does not exist. Use of DT_RPATH is deprecated.
>
> o Using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Except if the
>   executable is a set-user-ID/set-group-ID binary, in which case it is
>   ignored.
>
> ...

Also `LD_PRELOAD` may change things, though this is unlikely in your case.

You may find `LD_DEBUG` variable useful, just run your program like `LD_DEBUG=libs myprog` (see same man page for help and more options).